# Does a Substrate Private Network require the initial node to be alive?

Tags: substrate

I worked through the "Start a Private Network with Subtrate" [tutorial](https://substrate.dev/docs/en/tutorials/start-a-private-network/), and I successfully created numerous (4) nodes and connected them (all just different ports on localhost, just to see it work).  In the [Polkadot JS App](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=ws%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A9945#/explorer/node) I can see the three connected nodes.  There is no sign of failure that I can tell.

The main node (the one I initiated the network on) shows much more verbose output, such as:

```
2021-03-27 23:43:06   Starting consensus session on top of parent 0x454cabefd4df941f0dcee9302a12974fc60150fd75b753b9858517e767997e72    
2021-03-27 23:43:06   Prepared block for proposing at 83 [hash: 0x9db6e2d0ef6da5b42a68652d17cac38f9c26415e747d43f69e3c26b87b1d0d1e; parent_hash: 0x454c…7e72; extrinsics (1): [0x4e86…067c]]    
2021-03-27 23:43:06   Pre-sealed block for proposal at 83. Hash now 0x646e5c26e4c18f0e1e91603b8d47fe9fdd15b5bc88c69346f32c8e7078cc7532, previously 0x9db6e2d0ef6da5b42a68652d17cac38f9c26415e747d43f69e3c26b87b1d0d1e.
```

whereas the other nodes show only many repetitions of the like (as well as idle messages):

```
2021-03-27 23:44:18  ✨ Imported #86 (0x2247…ffac)
```

My hope is that in killing the "primary" node, the other 3 would continue to run and process blocks, but when I kill the main node, everything stops.

Most likely this is a failure of my understanding of what I'm doing here, but figured I'd ask and see if knowledge might rain down upon me.

Thanks in advance for taking the time to assist.

Comment: How were your authorities configured in your chainspec?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @NukeManDan.  palletAura authorities are (per the tutorial guide as i read it) the sr25519-schemed SS58 addresses (simple list, node1 thru node4), while the palletGrandpa authorities are list-of-lists, with the first item of each being the ed25519-schemed SS58 address for each of the four nodes.

Comment: indeed :) - can you provide a snippet or repo showing your authorities list? The template *only* provides Alice as an aura authority [here](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/8370ddd69caf4fe8c6251b99b2f6f3ea0008de8e/node/src/chain_spec.rs#L54)

Comment: thanks for sharing.  [here](https://github.com/bmacer/substrate-private-network) is my code.  tutorial doesn't have me adjust the node/src/chain_spec.rs file (not directly at least).  guessing i need to add something there to get my nodes 2-4 to be authorities from the start, or is this configured elsewhere?  thanks again.

Comment: oh fwiw this is a re-run of a previous implementation, so there are only two nodes (in case you're wondering why customSpec.json only has two authorities for each aura and gran.

Comment: If the authorities are [not in the list](https://github.com/bmacer/substrate-private-network/blob/c2009b1a84f696f382dee0d4d0c7b923771571e4/node/src/chain_spec.rs#L91-L94), or added via extrinsic after you start up the network, BUT the `aura` pallet is simple: there is no way to update this [after genesis](https://substrate.dev/rustdocs/v3.0.0/pallet_aura/pallet/struct.GenesisConfig.html) like other block production pallets (like BABE).

Comment: As you have alice and bob as authorities, can you have only one of these (with the right keys installed) running? Try with the `--alice` and `--bob` flags to have them startup with the right keys (IIRC) and see if blocks keep up